# How to do $\frac{ \partial { \mathrm{tr}(XX^TXX^T)}}{\partial X}$

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How to do the derivative 
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial {\mathrm{tr}(XX^TXX^T)}}{\partial X}\quad ?
\end{equation}

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What does $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}$ mean if $X$ is a matrix?

Comment: You could start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_matrices

Comment: @Learner Thanks but is there any trick I can use if the function is $tr(XX^TXX^T)$?

Comment: @Rein, the derivative is really the "linear part" of a function, so if you want to take the derivative at $A$, write $X = A+H$, and capture the linear part involving $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the derivative of $F(X)=tr(XX^TXX^T)$, in the point $X$, is the only linear functional $DF(X):{\rm M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$  such that
$$
F(x+H)=F(X)+DF(X)\cdot H+r(H)
$$ 
with $\lim_{H\to 0} \frac{r(H)}{\|H\|}=0$. Let's get $DF(X)(H)$ and $r(H)$ by the expansion of $F(X+H)$. But first we must do an algebraic manipulation to expand $(X+H)(X+H)^T(X+H)(X+H)^T$. In fact, 
\begin{align}
(X+\color{red}{H})(X+\color{red}{H})^T(X+\color{red}{H})(X+\color{red}{H})^T
=&
(X+\color{red}{H})(X^T+\color{red}{H}^T)\big(XX^T+X\color{red}{H}^T+\color{red}{H}X^T+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T\big)
\\
=&(X+\color{red}{H})\Big(X^TXX^T+X^TX\color{red}{H}^T+X^T\color{red}{H}X^T+X^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T
\\
&\hspace{12mm}+\color{red}{H}^TXX^T+\color{red}{H}^TX\color{red}{H}^T+\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}X^T+\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T\Big)
\\
=&\;\;\;\;\,XX^TXX^T+XX^TX\color{red}{H}^T+XX^T\color{red}{H}X^T+XX^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T
\\
&+X\color{red}{H}^TXX^T+X\color{red}{H}^TX\color{red}{H}^T+X\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}X^T+X\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T
\\
&+\color{red}{H}X^TXX^T+\color{red}{H}X^TX\color{red}{H}^T+\color{red}{H}X^T\color{red}{H}X^T+\color{red}{H}X^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T
\\
&+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^TXX^T+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^TX\color{red}{H}^T+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}X^T+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T
\end{align}
Extracting $XX^TXX^T$ and the portions where $H$ or $H^T$ appears only once and applying $tr$ we have
\begin{align}
F(X+H)=&tr\Big( 
(X+\color{red}{H})(X^T+\color{red}{H}^T)(X+\color{red}{H})(X^T+\color{red}{H}^T)
\Big)
\\
=&\underbrace{tr \big(XX^TXX^T\big)}_{F(X)}
+\underbrace{tr\big(
 XX^TX\color{red}{H}^T+XX^T\color{red}{H}X^T
+X\color{red}{H}^TXX^T+\color{red}{H}X^TXX^T
\big)}_{DF(X)\cdot H}
\\
&+tr\Big(XX^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T
+X\color{red}{H}^TX\color{red}{H}^T+X\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}X^T+X\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T
\\
&\hspace{12mm}+\color{red}{H}X^TX\color{red}{H}^T+\color{red}{H}X^T\color{red}{H}X^T+\color{red}{H}X^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T
\\
&\underbrace{\hspace{12mm}+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^TXX^T+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^TX\color{red}{H}^T+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}X^T+\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T\color{red}{H}\color{red}{H}^T\Big)}_{r(H)}
\end{align}
Here $\|H\|=\sqrt{tr(HH^T)}$ is the Frobenius norm and $\displaystyle\lim_{H\to 0}\frac{r(H)}{H}=0$. Then the total derivative is
\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}F(X)\cdot H =
& 
tr\bigg(XX^TXH^T\bigg)+ tr\bigg(XX^THX^T\bigg)
\\
+
&
tr\bigg(XH^TXX^T \bigg)+ tr\bigg(HX^TXX^T \bigg).
\\
\end{align}

The directional derivative is 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial V}F(X)=\mathcal{D}F(X)\cdot V
$$
and the partial derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial E_{ij}}F(X)=\mathcal{D}F(X)\cdot E_{ij}.
$$
Here $E_{ij}=[\delta_{ij}]_{n\times m}$.

Answer (score 4):

Write it down in terms of components. You want to know
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \mathop{\rm tr}(X X^T X X^T)
=\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} ( X_{kl} X_{ml} X_{mn} X_{kn}), $$
where summation over repeated indices is implied. Using the fact that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} X_{mn} =\delta_{im} \delta_{jn}$$
yields
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \mathop{\rm tr}(X X^T X X^T)
&= \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl} X_{ml} X_{mn} X_{kn}
 + \delta_{im} \delta_{jl} X_{kl} X_{mn} X_{kn}
+ \delta_{im} \delta_{jn} X_{kl} X_{ml}  X_{kn}
+ \delta_{ik} \delta_{jn}  X_{kl} X_{ml} X_{mn} \\
&= X_{mj} X_{mn} X_{in}+X_{kj} X_{in} X_{kn}
 + X_{kl} X_{il}  X_{kj} +X_{il} X_{ml} X_{mj}\\
&=4(X X^T X)_{ij} .
\end{align}$$

Or in short notation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \mathop{\rm tr}(X X^T X X^T) = 4 X X^T X.$$

Comment: You are assuming that the matrices are square and commute? We can not assume these properties.

Comment: @Elias: I did not assume any of those. Or where do you spot that I assume something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Define a new matrix variable $$M=XX^T$$ and write the function in terms of this new variable and the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product. 
When written in this form, finding the differential and gradient is easy
$$\eqalign{
 f &= M:M \cr
\cr
df &= 2\,M:dM \cr
  &= 2\,M:(dX\,X^T+X\,dX^T) \cr
  &= 2\,(M+M^T):dX\,X^T \cr
  &= 4\,MX:dX \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= 4\,MX \cr
 &= 4\,XX^TX \cr
\cr
}$$
For reference, the double-dot product is defined such that $$A:B=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$$